# Can't access property of extended class with new instance throught ajax Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I will give below code example to better explain:

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
    public $globalCurrencies;
    public $currentCurrency;
    public $globalLanguages;
    public $currentLanguage;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->globalCurrencies = $this->getCurrencies();
        $this->globalLanguages = $this->getLanguages();

        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->currentCurrency = $this->getCurrentCurrency();
            $this->currentLanguage = $this->getCurrentLanguage();
            return $next($request);
        });
    }
```

CartController

```
class CartController extends BaseController
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
```

BaseController sets up base variables for the app. The cart is using some of them like (current currency). Some of the variables are session based so in base construct there is middleware used to get session data in the constructor). For this part, everything works and cart has access to baseController properties.

Problem occurs here:

```
class OrderController extends BaseController
{
    public function loadPaymentsAndDelivery(Request $request)
    {
        $cart = new Cart;
        dd($cart->globalCurrencies) // WORKS
        dd($cart->currentCurrency)  // NULL
    }
}
```

Basically, on a new Cart instance, I can access every property created without middleware. Without middleware, I cannot access the session to set up the cart. Method loadPaymentsAndDelivery is loaded via ajax but I tried directly call the method and the properties were still null.

Can somebody explain why this is happening?

Comment: You can use implicit binding I guess, have you tried?

Comment: Can You give me some example  of implicit binding? I saw in docs article about that and it looks like  binding model with controller/or route but I am not sure.

Comment: Is `currentCurrency` a property of the `Cart` model? Or did you mean to do `$this->currentCurrency`?

Comment: currentCurrency is property of  BaseController. CartController (not model) extends BaseController so he has access to it.

Comment: @MarekKaliszuk But he's creating an instance of `Cart` (not `CartController`) and trying to access `currentCurrency` from this instance.

Comment: Which php version are you using? In older versions of php $this is not passed to closures.

Comment: It's 7.1 version